Azure data factory : Loading duplicate data
In Azure data factory What if we receive same source CSV data again as last load to load the data into Target.
Below is the situation.
I've received one CSV file in blob storage name data_2023_04_24.csv contains below data,
colA, colB
1A, 1B
and copied this data into SQL Server table (full refresh).
Next day, received same file name data_2023_04_25.csv which contains same data as mentioned. Now I don't want to run the pipeline further or Fail the pipeline so that I can create alerts for having same data and in source and target.
Is there any approach how we can handle this scenario in Azure Data Factory.

Do you want to copy only files which are not present in the sink container?

You can use the below approach to copy only the new or updated files from the source to the sink in Azure Data Factory. You can use two Get Metadata activities in parallel to get the child items list of the source and sink. Then, you can use a Filter activity to filter out the files that are already present in the sink. Then, you can use a For Each activity to iterate through the filtered list and copy the missing files.
Steps:

Take two get metadata activities. One for source file list and other for sink file list. Add child items as argument in both activities.



Take the filter activity and give the expression for items as @activity('source file list').output.childItems . Give the expression for condition as @not(contains(activity('sink file list').output.childItems,item()))

Then take the foreach activity and in foreach settings give the expression for items as @activity('Filter1').output.Value .


Inside foreach, add the copy activity to copy only the filtered files to sink.


This way, you can avoid copying duplicate files in ADF.

Hi @Aswin, so below is the situation.
I've received one CSV file in blob storage name data_2023_04_24.csv contains data
colA, colB
1A, 1B
and copied this data into SQL Server table (full refresh).
Next day.. received same file name data_2023_04_25.csv which contains same data
as mentioned above.
colA, colB
1A, 1B
Now i do not want to run the pipeline further or Fail the pipeline so that I can create alerts that for having same data and in source and target. Your answer is helpful however this will check based on file name and not the data we have I believe.

Yeah..This approach is based on file only and not for data. Could you ask a new question with more explanantion so that it would be easy for community members to help you

I've edit the question. Thanks @Aswin. Let me know if there is any approach to handle this scenario

You can use upsert in ADF dataflow to insert or update only the new or modified records
